# Bootstrap slider does not display precision

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/q6HuW/

```
$("#ex9").slider({
    precision: 2,
    value: 8.115 // Slider will instantiate showing 8.12 due to specified precision
});
```

Pretty simple, the precision is supposed to add a 2 digit decimal place to slider when dragged, yet it does nothing on the fiddle:

but works on his page:

http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/q6HuW/3/ (if you inspect the source you will see that this one is the right code, not the posted one there...)

Comment: that works im guessing the precision is deprecated

Comment: I don't know it may be deprecated or just a mistake in the demo... I don't like using boostrap so I'm not too familiar with their changes on the code...